# Joint normal distribution factorizes if covariance matrix is diagonal. Why?

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, normal-distribution, covariance, density-function

I am given that

> joint normal distribution factorizes if the covariance matrix is
> diagonal

I was wondering why such a fact holds true. Is there a rigorous way to show that? Any reference would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: A diagonal covariance matrix means independance for gaussian vectors. And if X and Y are independent then the joint density is the product of the densities.

Comment: Why "A diagonal covariance matrix means independance for gaussian vectors."? Why is that specific for gaussian vectors? @nicomezi

Comment: This is surely not specific to gaussian vectors, but for them it is true.

Comment: Sorry but I am not comfortable with such things by now. Ok, in the specific case, why is it true for Gaussian vectors? How can one show this fact? @nicomezi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jointly normal distributions are parametrized by their means and covariance matrices (think about characteristic function of a normal random variable: the only two parameters involved are exactly mean and variance).  Independent random variables have covariance $0$: conversely, jointly normal random variables with covariance $0$ have the same mean and covariance as independent normal random variables, and therefore the same distribution.

Comment: Why can I state that "jointly normal random variables with covariance 0 have the same mean and covariance as independent normal random variables"? Does covariance 0 imply independence? @Robert Israel

Comment: In the case of normal variables, exceptionally, the two properties "0 covariance" and "independence" are equivalent.

Comment: You mean "**Joint** normal random variables", don't you? @JeanMarie

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: thank you a lot @JeanMarie

Comment: Here an explicit explanation about why for joint normal r.v.'s properties "0 covariance" and "independence" are equivalent (e.g. for bivariate case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849738/why-exceptionally-for-joint-normal-random-variables-does-it-hold-true-that-0