# Why, exceptionally, for joint normal random variables does it hold true that $0$ covariance between their components is equivalent to independence?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, normal-distribution, independence, covariance

For any generic random variables $X$ and $Y$, we know that
$$X\perp \!\!\! \perp Y \implies \text{Cov}(X,Y)=0\tag{1}$$ but not viceversa. 
 Now, let us consider two random variables $X$, $Y$, whose joint distribution $(X, Y)$ is normal. Why in this case does it hold true that:

$$ X \perp \!\!\! \perp Y \iff \text{Cov}(X,Y)=0\tag{2}$$?

---

Could you please explicit your reasoning, specifying **why normal joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is essential for $(2)$ to hold**?

Comment: Actually you need to assume $(X, Y) $ to be bivariate normal distributed as well. And then you see the covariance being zero is equivalent to factorization of the densities, so...

Comment: Oh right, silly error of mine, I immediately edit, thanks. So, with $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, why does $(2)$ hold true? @Shashi

Comment: Could you please briefly explicit your reasoning, specifying why bivariate normal distribution is essential for $(2)$ to hold? @Shashi

Comment: maybe look at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: In the bivariate normal case, zero-covariance implies that the covariance matrix is diagonal, which then implies that the joint p.d.f. factors into the product of the marginal p.d.f.s, which then implies the independence. So the answer critically relies on the structure of the bivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's $X$, $Y$ be jointly gaussian.

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\Bigg\{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\Bigg[\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2}-2\rho\frac{(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}+\frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\Bigg]\Bigg\}\tag{1}$$

Now, recalling that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $f_{XY}(x, y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, if you set $\rho=0$ in $(1)$ you get:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

and we are done.